# Can Pascal units be compiled as executables?

Tags: pascal, program-entry-point, fpc, scriptedmain

I like my libraries to double as executables. The desired behavior is:

```
$ ./scriptedmain
Main: The meaning of life is: 42
$ ./test
Test: The meaning of life is: 42
```

How can I:

- Get `scriptedmain.p` to compile into a `scriptedmain` binary?
- Prevent `test.p` from running the code that's in `scriptedmain.p`'s `begin`/`end` section?

scriptedmain.p:

```
unit ScriptedMain;
    interface

    function MeaningOfLife () : integer;

    implementation

    function MeaningOfLife () : integer;
    begin
        MeaningOfLife := 42
    end;
begin
    write('Main: The meaning of life is: ');
    writeln(MeaningOfLife())
end.
```

When I compile scriptedmain.p with `fpc scriptedmain.p`, no executable is created, because Pascal detects that it's a unit. But I want it to be an executable in addition to a library.

```
$ ./scriptedmain
-bash: ./scriptedmain: No such file or directory
```

test.p:

```
program Test;
uses
    ScriptedMain;
begin
    write('Test: The meaning of life is: ');
    writeln(MeaningOfLife())
end.
```

When I compile test.p with `fpc test.p`, the resulting executable combines the two `begin`/`end` declarations (NOT the desired behavior).

```
$ ./test 
Main: The meaning of life is: 42
Test: The meaning of life is: 42
```

Comment: So, use an empty main program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Ager and Zhirov in the Free Pascal [mailing list](http://lists.freepascal.org/mailman/listinfo/fpc-pascal/), I was able to construct a working scripted main example with minimal hacks. Also posted on [RosettaCode](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Scripted_main#Free_Pascal).

Makefile:

```
all: scriptedmain

scriptedmain: scriptedmain.pas
    fpc -dscriptedmain scriptedmain.pas

test: test.pas scriptedmain
    fpc test.pas

clean:
    -rm test
    -rm scriptedmain
    -rm *.o
    -rm *.ppu
```

scriptedmain.pas:

```
{$IFDEF scriptedmain}
program ScriptedMain;
{$ELSE}
unit ScriptedMain;
interface
function MeaningOfLife () : integer;
implementation
{$ENDIF}
    function MeaningOfLife () : integer;
    begin
        MeaningOfLife := 42
    end;
{$IFDEF scriptedmain}
begin
    write('Main: The meaning of life is: ');
    writeln(MeaningOfLife())
{$ENDIF}
end.
```

test.pas:

```
program Test;
uses
    ScriptedMain;
begin
    write('Test: The meaning of life is: ');
    writeln(MeaningOfLife())
end.
```

Example:

```
$ make
$ ./scriptedmain 
Main: The meaning of life is: 42
$ make test
$ ./test 
Test: The meaning of life is: 42
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what flavour of Pascal you're using but some variants support conditional compilation with `{$IFC condition} ... {$ENDC}`. You could perhaps use this in conjunction with a compile time define to include/exclude code that you need or don't need in a given version.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Free Pascal but you should be able to check the documentation and see if it supports conditional compilation.

Comment: It does, multiple types even. Turbo Pascal, Delphi, Mac Pascal/Codewarrior, what you want.